# How to remove special characters from a XML Document?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, special-characters, libxml2

Input:

```
<author>John & Fleck</author>

<date>Jun<e> 2002</date>

<keyword>example <keyword</keyword>
```

Output:

```
<author>John  Fleck</author>

<date>June 2002</date>

<keyword>example keyword</keyword>
```

I want to keep the xml doc intact and remove the special characters as you can see in the above example

Comment: The input you have shown does not adhere to XML syntax rules so any XML parser will simply give a parsing error. Don't expect to be able to use XML tools with such input. A tag soup parser might help though those are usually geared towards parsing HTML tag soup.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen

Answer (score 0):

You're not trying to remove special characters from an XML Document.

You're trying to convert a non-XML document to XML.

To do that you need to parse the non-XML document, and to do that you need to know (a) the grammar to which it conforms and (b) the rules for how this grammar maps to the grammar of XML.

You haven't told us anything about this grammar; you've just given one example of a non-XML document, and that's not enough to infer the general rules.

Comment: Hey Michael this grammar basically follows all rules of a well formed xml document.

Comment: The grammar of XML prohibits an unescaped `&`, and it prohibits the unclosed `<e>` element. This is not XML.

Comment: I know that this is not xml, but I want a method to convert this to a xml doc. Which follows all xml rulee. I want to remove all the characters that will give error on parsing it through an xml parser

Comment: Repairing broken XML is best avoided - it's much better to avoid breaking it in the first place - but if you need to do it, then the techniques depend greatly on how much of it you've got and whether you have accurate understanding of the nature of the faults that need to be repaired. Dealing with that `<e>`, for example, is very difficult unless you know for sure that your document will never contain an element named `e`.